# What do double curly braces ({{) mean in YAML files (as used by Ansible)?

Tags: ansible

I'm fairly new to Ansible and trying to understand the YAML file. In that i'm not clear about this piece of line - `file: dest={{ '{{' }} docroot {{ '}}' }`. Can some one please explain me what those curly braces '{{' '}}' are doing?

```
- name: Create Web Root

    when: nginxinstalled|success

    file: dest={{ '{{' }} docroot {{ '}}' }} mode=775 state=directory owner=www-data group=www-data

  notify:

      - Reload Nginx
```

Comment: Where did you get this example?  It looks like this play is being setup for parsing by a second Jinja2 execution.  The result would be "dest={{ docroot }} mode=755 ..."

Comment: Only some of those files are YAML files. They are regular files that can be used as templates from which YAML files can be generated.

Answer (score 21):

I found this [YAML syntax overview](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/YAMLSyntax.html) in Ansible documantation, to be fairly useful.

It says that double curly braces `{{ variable }}` are used to evaluate expressions. Whilst distinguishing a single curly braces (after a colon), that is used to declare a dictionary. For example:

```
satchmo: {name: Louis Armstrong, music: Jazz, instrument: Trumpet}
```

Also, take a look at [Jinja Template Designer Documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/). Jinja template is rendered before YAML, which means it is evaluated prior to Ansible execution.

```
{% ... %} for Statements
{{ ... }} for Expressions to print to the template output
{# ... #} for Comments not included in the template output
#  ... ## for Line Statements
```

Comment: sometimes I am seeing a dash used, e.g. `{{- if ...}} or {{- end }}`, why is this?

Comment: @boardtc Maybe that is Helm? They use `{{-` to left trim whitespace, and `-}}` to right trim whitespace. https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures/

Answer (score 17):

Ansible uses the jinja2 template

the `{{ }}` are used to evaluate the expression inside them from the context passed.

So `{{ '{{' }}` evaluates to the string `{{`

And the while expression `{{ docroot }}` is written to a template, where `docroot` could be another template variable

refer https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-container/container_yml/template.html for more details.

Comment: So what exactly is the purpose of `{{ '{{' }}` in the example given?

Comment: The link is dead